# Nginx GET atack

Tags: nginx

how can I block this request methoh, because I consume all my limits at vps, and the site becomes unavailable. I set it but it does not count in nginx.conf

```
 map $request_method $limit {
default         "";
    POST            $binary_remote_addr;
}
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m rate=1r/s;
limit_req_zone $server_name zone=perserver:10m rate=10r/s;
```

and in common_http.conf

```
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
return 405;
}
try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
```

request from nginx access.log

```
200.98.247.2 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "-"
    187.17.96.25 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "-"
    184.168.46.123 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 0 "-" "-"
    187.17.96.29 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "-"
    200.98.247.2 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "-"
    85.31.185.2 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "-"
    94.73.148.10 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "-"
    94.73.148.10 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "-"
    94.73.148.10 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "-"
    94.73.148.10 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "-"
    200.98.247.2 - - [02/Oct/2018:00:37:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Can you try adding this statement before your `if` statement 
`add_header Allow "POST, HEAD" always;`

Comment: hello, They are the same problems, the behavior has not changed Another idea?

Comment: How about using `limit_except POST {
        deny all;     
    }` directive

Comment: I need to block requests of this type GET HEAD and POST,  because uses my CPU to the maximum